# CSS cut off my image

Tags: html, css, displaytag, text-align

The site should looks like:
http://funedit.com/imgedit/soubory/small_17663057361396452975.jpg

But it actualy looks like:
http://funedit.com/andurit/ (it cut that warning image and also move it on left site instead of right.

Can someboddy help me and explain me what i am doing wrong, i am newbie in CSS

My HTML:

```
 <body> 
 <div class="top-panel">
    <div id="center"> <a class="top-button" href="#"></a>
       <span class="text">Prave hraje <b>5000</b> hracov na <b>150</b> serveroch!</span>
       <span class="panel">Registruj sa zdarma nebo</span>
        <input type="text">
        <input type="text">
        <input type="image" id="login-button" src="images/login_button.png" alt="Submit">
       <div class="tournament"> Night Cup 2014 - Sledujte priamy prenos! </div> 
    </div>
 </div>
 </body>
```

my CSS:

```
body {
    background-image:url('images/background.png');
    background-color:#cccccc;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#center {
    width: 1030px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /*display: inline-block; */
}
.top-panel {
    background-image: url("images/top_panel.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    background-position: center;
    height: 43px;
    padding-top:5px;
    display: block;
}
a.top-button {
    background-image: url("images/top_button.png");
    height: 37px;
    width: 141px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 50px;
}
.text {
    color: #9c9c9c;
    padding: 0px 10px;
}
.panel {
    color: #6ab1ed;
    padding: 0px 350px;
    display: inline-block;
}
input{
    vertical-align:top;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 25px;
    line-height: 25px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative; left: 510px; top: 2px;
}
span{
    position: absolute;
    display: inline-block;
    height: 35px;
    line-height: 35px;
    text-align: center;    
}
span b{
    font-weight:bold;
}
#login-button{
    /*background-image: url("images/login_button.png");   uz je to v HTML*/
    height: 27px;
    width: 81px;
    line-height: 27px;
    display: inline-block;
    position: relative; left: 510px; top: 4px; 
}
.tournament{
    background-image: url("images/warning.png");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    text-align: right;
    display: block;
    color: #d4d4d4;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

```
body { background-size: 100%;}
.tournament{
  width: 30%;
  right: 10%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 30px;
}
```

Comment: I make that change and u can see it live, it change site a bit but didnt help with that icon :(

Comment: add also for tournament

Comment: I hate this row: `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="120">` :)

Comment: if i do that it show whole image but it also resize it and i dont want it :(

Comment: set sizes of this block to equal to whole image

Comment: i am not sure what u mean now, size of the image is 35x30. Man btw thanks for trying to help me

Comment: are you get what you want with `height: 30px` ?

Answer (score 0):

You are setting the image as a background-image. While 'text-align' does move the text to the right, background-images are unaffected by that.

Just change the code into:

```
<div class="tournament"
    <img src="..." /> 
    Night Cup 2014 - Sledujte priamz prenos!
</div>
```

so it will align with the text.

Comment: it may explain the position of image not it cut man, am i right?

Comment: it actually does. The div is only as high as the text is. And the background image only gets drawn where the div is visible. Try testing it using Chrome Developer tools (right click -> inspect element)

Comment: THere is no other wa then to add image to a HTML?

Comment: Adding an image to a webpage is normally done by adding an image to your html. That is what an <img> is for, for images ;-)

Comment: in my opinion images which are not changing should be in CSS instead of HTML, there should be just things that change because u can easy use it with some app

Comment: and in my opinion, a warning should have a 'warning' class and not a 'tournament' class. But it all depends on the situation. I would have done it using pseudo content (:before) to automagically insert the warning sign if something gets a 'warning' class. Result: image gets inserted as 'content' and will stick to text-align, however, you don't have to insert the image in your html. Win-win situation!